# Why isn't all of the code in my in my findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^ being executed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

This is the code I have as part of my ViewDidLoad

I'm trying to do something in the part of the code where i have the NSLogs which aren't be executed. I haven't been able to find anyone with the same issue?

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
PFRelation *relation = [staffMember relationForKey:@"completedTraining"];
PFQuery *query = [relation query];
[query includeKey:@"trainingRecordPointer"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *completedTrainingRecords, NSError *error){
    if(!error){
        for (PFObject* completedTrainingRecord in completedTrainingRecords) {
            PFObject * recordWtihTypeAndName = [completedTrainingRecord objectForKey:@"trainingRecordPointer"];
            PFObject *outputObject = [[PFObject alloc]initWithClassName:@"NewTrainingRecord"];
            NSString *recordName = [recordWtihTypeAndName valueForKey:@"RecordName"];
            [completeRecordsWithType addObject:recordName];
            [outputObject addObject:recordName forKey:@"recordName"];
            [outputObject addObject:completedTrainingRecord.createdAt forKey:@"date"];
            [[trainingRecordsDictionary objectForKey:[recordWtihTypeAndName objectForKey:@"Type"]] addObject:outputObject];
            [self.tableView reloadData]; //it works up to this point but if I move this line outside
            //the for-loop nothing happens
            NSLog(@"this will execute"); // does execute

        }
        NSLog(@"this wont execute"); // doesn't execute

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    NSLog(@"this wont execute"); // doesn't execute

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `[self.tableView reloadData];` to outside your for-loop.

You should also make sure the tableview is reloaded on the mainthread, and not in this background thread.

Maybe like this:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *completedTrainingRecords, NSError *error){
    if(!error){
        for (PFObject* completedTrainingRecord in completedTrainingRecords) {

                 ... do your stuff ...

        }
         __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                  [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
}];
```

You probably get into trouble because you try to modify your UI on a backgroundthread.

Comment: It needs to be done on the background thread because the data i'm getting from parse is what I'm using to populate the tableview. If I did it on the  main thread there wouldn't be any point doing it. I would do it outside the loop but nothing outside the loop is being executed. That's my probelem...

Comment: Yes you do your fetching from Parse on this background thread but if you want to update your UI you need to do this on the mainthread. I updated my anser to give you an example how this can be done.

Comment: Even if I comment out [tableView reloadData] the NSLogs aren't being executed.. Thanks for the example though. Good to know.

Comment: So it probably crash somewhere in the loop (even if its strange that your app don't crash). Did you try to add a breakpoint a step through until it stop executing? There are manyplaces in your code that can make it crash. e.g. `[outputObject addObject:recordName forKey:@"recordName"];` will crash if `recordName` is `nil`

Comment: Yes it was exactly that! I had some objects that were pointing to data that were no longer in my database and that was causing it to crash without telling me that it was doing that. I'll mark this as the accepted answer but maybe you might want to edit it a bit to let people who might find this in the future exactly what the problem was! Thanks so much! I've upvoted it as well but because I don't have 15 reputation yet it won't show up.. Sorry!